# Power Center view result

Tags: etl, informatica-powercenter

I'm starting working with Informatica Power Center, I'm new in this technology. In the past I worked with Datastage. I made a task that read data from an Oracle table and write them on a Flat File. The Job run and finish correctly (I saw on Workflow Manger).

Is there a way to view the records written on my flat file on Power Center?

Thanks

Luca

Comment: go to the target directory and open the file informatica generated. You can see the target file path from session log.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the output file. Informatica does not provide a data browser to inspect flat files or databases. You need to use a separate tool.
Try FTP or SSH connection to wherever the output file got generated.